# Kernel Notices UFW Block

Tags: syslog, ufw

Running a public wordpress site and every few minutes I am seeing these kind of entries on my syslog on my ubuntu server. (I have hidden my mac/ip address in the logs below) What is happening here?

```
 Nov 27 20:00:58 kernel: [156727.115812] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=2.40.220.141 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=56784 PROTO=TCP SPT=63030 DPT=7547 WINDOW=32852 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:01:22 kernel: [156751.426722] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=82.78.180.169 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=1500 PROTO=TCP SPT=17375 DPT=23 WINDOW=22727 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:01:37 kernel: [156766.978914] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=195.154.181.110 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=35970 PROTO=TCP SPT=52845 DPT=4937 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:01:53 kernel: [156782.801964] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=119.177.186.133 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=48838 PROTO=TCP SPT=41526 DPT=23 WINDOW=29917 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:02:41 kernel: [156830.201481] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=177.207.61.71 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=46 ID=3825 PROTO=TCP SPT=50321 DPT=7547 WINDOW=56458 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:04:17 kernel: [156926.284028] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=104.216.4.228 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=7655 PROTO=TCP SPT=57031 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:04:30 kernel: [156939.465199] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=59.1.129.240 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=49 ID=7320 PROTO=TCP SPT=3183 DPT=23 WINDOW=6007 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:04:32 kernel: [156941.208844] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=77.86.57.9 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=43928 PROTO=TCP SPT=41599 DPT=7547 WINDOW=18922 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:04:45 kernel: [156954.272382] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=46.44.4.175 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=248 ID=49549 PROTO=TCP SPT=57081 DPT=3389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
    Nov 27 20:05:09 kernel: [156978.634250] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=**:**:**:hidden SRC=61.240.144.66 DST=**:**:**:hidden LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=236 ID=61341 PROTO=TCP SPT=56806 DPT=81 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your system is blocking access to a range of IP addresses. Do you have fail2ban, denyhosts, or something similar installed that generate/collect lists of IP addresses to block ?

Comment: Yes I am using fail2ban. Is this expected ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kamermans/1076290

Comment: not sure, do I need to take any additional action here or should I leave things as they are ?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment due to reputation so here it is as an answer.

I don't think you need to do anything, fail2ban appears to be doing its job to block malicious hosts.

I found what I think are malicious requests in the logs for my testing web server.  As you can see it's coming from one of the IP addresses in your question (I found this page searching for that IP address):

```
195.154.181.110 - - [01/Dec/2016 04:53:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
195.154.181.110 - - [01/Dec/2016 04:53:38] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00^\x01\x00\x00Z\x03\x01X?\x9eÀ\x88È¾\x00Ô\x92Ïà@©\x13¼\x81ß')
195.154.181.110 - - [01/Dec/2016 04:53:38] "\00^\00\00ZX?ÀÈ¾\00ÔÏà@©¼ß5ØÂ²/Re­aÓËù\00\00\00/\005\00\00" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
195.154.181.110 - - [01/Dec/2016 04:53:38] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00^\x01\x00\x00Z\x03\x01X?\x9eÀ¯\x1cÁ\x19ñ\x1bÑ\x82?2ì\x8d\xa0±83)D\x82h\x0cÏ?\x99\x00\x1d\x01%\x00\x00\x18\x00/\x005\x00\x05\x00')
195.154.181.110 - - [01/Dec/2016 04:53:38] "\00^\00\00ZX?À¯ÁñÑ?2ì ±83)DhÏ?\00%\00\00\00/\005\00\00" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
195.154.181.110 - - [02/Dec/2016 20:27:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
195.154.181.110 - - [02/Dec/2016 20:27:45] code 400, message Bad request version ('o|AÁMÿü\x00\x00\x18\x00/\x005\x00\x05\x00')
195.154.181.110 - - [02/Dec/2016 20:27:45] "\00Z\00\00VXB;°YÝö¾k`wè¡~Q¯*¤?V o|AÁMÿü\00\00\00/\005\00\00" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
195.154.181.110 - - [02/Dec/2016 20:27:45] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00Z\x01\x00\x00V\x03\x01XB;°')
195.154.181.110 - - [02/Dec/2016 20:27:45] "\00Z\0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are always lots of servers running port scans on the internet. They're usually looking for open services and vulnerable servers to use as unreachable sources of attacks, for example

Comment: I forgot to say, ufw comes with a set of rules already installed.